# jcvl not working due to jcl requirements

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, jvcl, jedi-code-library

I am trying to manually install `JCL` and `jvcl` for delphi xe2.

I have installed JCL as directed and it seems to have installed with no issues. 
Now I try to load the JVCL package 16 , it opens delphi and starts to load libarys, When it gets to the Jedi code Library MPL1.1 i start to get errors like below

```
Error reading form frmJucolorProviderDesigner
-class tjvcontextprovider not found

Ingnore Cancel Ingnore all
```

this is not the only one i get quite a few ill post a few more in case it helps

```
Error reading form JvStandardActions
 -tjvSendMailAction not found
 -tjvwebaction not found
Error reading form jvCheckItemsEditor
 -tjvCheckListBox not found
Error reading form JvControlActoinsDM
 -tjvControlcollapseAction not found
 -TjvControlexpandAction not found
 -TjvControlExportAction not found
 -tjvControlOptimizeColumnsAction not found
 -TjvControlCustomizeColumnsAction not found
 -TjvControlPrintAction not found
Error reading form jvSpeedBarEditorMain
 -jvFormStorage not found
 -AppRegistryStorage not found
```

ect... I can add rest if you need.

But each - is its own dialog box with [ignore][cancel][ignore all]

Now after I press Ignore 50 times it will finally load the project, when i try to  build all the projects for JVCl package it says required package jcl not found.

in library path i have

```
..jcl\source\common
..jcl\source\windows
..jcl\source\include
```

in browsing path i have

```
..jcl\source\common
..jcl\source\vcl
..jcl\source\windows
```

and in DCU debug path i have

```
 ..jcl\lib\d16\win32\debug
```

Comment: The JCL tag is normally used for IBM's Job control language which runs on the IBM mainframe

Comment: @BruceMartin: I corrected it for him. There's a separate tag for the `Jedi Code Library`.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks did not know the tag was different,  Sooo... any idea on solving this?

Comment: You should have the dcp in your library path. Using the installer that is `..jcl\lib\d16\win32`, which contains the 32 bit `jcl.dcp`.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That seems to help,  I still get all the desgin time errors,  and when i start to build the project it starts with an error fmeJvSegmentedLEDDisplayMapper.sldEdit does not have a coresponding component. After i hit no, it builds unitll i get error file not found 'ComObj.dcu'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after adding

```
..jcl\lib\d16\win32, which contains the 32 bit jcl.dcp
```

The solution is to change the `uses` to use a fully qualified name:

```
uses
  TypInfo,
  {$IFDEF JvInterpreter_OLEAUTO}
  OleConst, ActiveX, 
  {$IFDEF VER230} system.win.ComObj, {$ELSE} ComObj, {$ENDIF}
```

Now it compiles without error.

Comment: If you'd prefer to use old style unit scope names, you might add (for this case) the `System.Win` namespace prefix e.g. globally to the [`Unit scope names`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Library) configuration option. This option is also available at project options level, not only in global settings scope.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following to your Search Path(HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\x.x\Library\Win32), of course including the correct path prefix:

```
..jcl\source;
..jcl\source\common;
..jcl\source\include;
..jcl\source\vcl;
..jcl\source\windows;

..jvcl\common;
..jvcl\run;
```

You might also be interested in the following link:
http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2013/05/how-to-install-jcl-and-jvcl-for-xe4/

Comment: i dont see a current folder,  i assume with out the current ?

Comment: after adding i still get errors, updated post maybe it will help?

Comment: also note that link is for xe4 and the auto version, I need manually install